# Docker Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

When I download a completely new Ubuntu:12.04 container from the Docker INDEX, nothing in it works. It doesn't even have sudo or lsb_release. Does anyone have any ideas why or how to get the container to a state where it is usable? Thanks.

Comment: define "the state that it is usable" first please. for me, bash works and you can pickup all precise dependencies over `apt-get`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general computing and not about programming.

Comment: please list the command you type and describe what it means for "nothing it works". Obviously it looks you already downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

It would be interesting to see what you did and to know what you expect. But here is a working example, maybe that helps:

```
# get the image
docker pull ubuntu

# run pwd in the image and see that you are in "/"
docker run ubuntu pwd
/

# curl a website and see that curl is not installed
docker run ubuntu curl www.google.com
2014/05/22 07:52:42 exec: "curl": executable file not found in $PATH

# update apt-get
docker run ubuntu apt-get update

# Now attention: Docker will not change the base image Ubuntu! 
# So apt is not updated in your Ubuntu image! Instead, Docker 
# will create a new container every time you run a command. Let's see 
# how the new container is called (your CONTAINER ID will be different!):
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS
a7ae5dae6dd8        ubuntu:12.04                      apt-get update         53 seconds ago      Exited (0) 40 seconds ago                                                     nostalgic_lumiere

# So container a7ae5dae6dd8 is Ubuntu + apt-get update. Give it
# a name and save it as a new image:
docker commit a7ae my-ubuntu

# Now install curl in my-ubuntu
docker run my-ubuntu apt-get install -y curl

# And again: the image my-ubuntu is not changed! Instead we have a new 
# container which has curl installed:
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS
e07118069479        my-ubuntu:latest                  apt-get install -y c   About a minute ago   Exited (0) 45 seconds ago                                                      naughty_wozniak
a7ae5dae6dd8        ubuntu:12.04                      apt-get update         9 minutes ago        Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                                                       nostalgic_lumiere

# Let's save this container as our image:
docker commit e071 my-ubuntu

# and now run curl on my-ubuntu:
docker run my-ubuntu curl www.google.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   258  100   258    0     0  10698      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25800
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=ZrB9U4_eH4HW_AbjvoG4Ag">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I hope that helps to see how Docker works. To get an image into a state to use (install your packages and stuff) you would of course not doing it by hand like above. Instead you would create a **Dockerfile** to build an image:

```
FROM Ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
```

And build your desired image like `docker build . -t my-ubuntu`.